# Fetch API cannot load https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=...

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-web-api2, fetch-api

I am running into an issue with my Reactjs app that interfaces with Web API 2 deployed to Azure with Microsoft Authentication where my initial `GET` request throws an error that says:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?
client_id=[...]&redirect_uri=[MY_REDIRECT_URL]. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin '[MY_AZURE_SITE]' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves 
your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I am really new to Azure and using React so I am unsure where i went wrong here. The weird part about this issue is that if I turn of Microsoft Authentication for my app it works as expected.

I have been stuck on this issue for a little while now, and am not really sure where I am going wrong. I also am not sure what information would be useful to help troubleshooting this issue so please feel free to comment asking for code/information and I will to update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get content from a different URL then your site originally host.
For security reasons APIs set some rules for requests. To be able to make requests you need to set up CORS. There for you need to set up appropriate headers for your requests.

You can read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a
>   resource from a different domain, protocol, or port to its own. For
>   example, an HTML page served from http://domain-a.com makes an 
>   src request for http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web
>   today load resources like CSS stylesheets, images, and scripts from
>   separate domains.
>
> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and Fetch
>   follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using
>   XMLHttpRequest or Fetch could only make HTTP requests to its own
>   domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors
>   to allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: The part that I don't understand, is that my React web page is hosted in the same place as my web api, and works perfectly fine without Microsoft Authentication.  Once enabling Microsoft Authentication, it breaks my requests. I could be wrong, but I wouldn't think that I should have to have CORS enabled to do get my Authentication to work.

Comment: It might be hosting at the same place but the URL you are making a request has a different origin then yours. you are making a request from `https://www.yourweburl.com` to `https://login.live.com`. Check for the CORS required headers and add them to your fetch requests as parameters.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I am not quite sure what those headers may be. Any ideas?